# Regex not working in bash (MacOS) when trying to validate commit message with husky

Tags: regex, bash, husky

I tried to write the next regex for checking GIT commit message with husky

My script:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env sh
. "$(dirname -- "$0")/_/husky.sh"

message="$(cat $1)"
if ! [[ $message =~ ^\[.*?\] (resolved|fixed) \#([0-9])* ([A-Z])\w.*$ ]];
then
  echo " Wrong commit message! "
  echo "[POLICY] Your message is not formatted correctly!"  
  echo "Message format must be like:"  
  echo "[Tag] resolved #123 Case title (for features)"
  echo "[Tag] fixed #123 Case title    (for bugs)"
  echo "First letter of 'Case title' must be capitalized!"  
  exit 1  
fi
```

Messages should pass:
[Tag] resolved #123 Case title (for features)
[Tag] fixed #123 Case title    (for bugs)

Error occurs:
`.husky/commit-msg: line 5: syntax error in conditional expression: unexpected token` ('`

Comment: Try `rx='^\[[^][]*] (resolved|fixed) #[0-9]* [A-Z][[:alnum:]_].*'` and then `if ! [[ "$message" =~ $rx ]];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use define the regex as

```bash
rx='^\[[^][]*] (resolved|fixed) #[0-9]* [A-Z][[:alnum:]_].*'
```

Then, you can use

```bash
if ! [[ "$message" =~ $rx ]];
```

Note:

- In a POSIX ERE regex, `*?` is not parsed as a lazy quantifier, thus `[^][]*` is used to match any zero or more chars other than `[` and `]`
- `\w` is not universally supported, thus it is better defined as `[[:alnum:]_]`
- It is safer to declare the regex as a variable inside single quotes to avoid special char expansion by Bash inside the unquoted pattern.